# Tagged articles selection - more complex case (tags defined by logical expression)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, tags

I know, its simple to select all articles with at least on of tags "14 OR 16 OR 17" ... (only simple disjunction) ...

```
SELECT _article_id from articles_x_tags
WHERE _id_tag in (14,16,17)
GROUP BY _id_article
```

How to do same thing (quick way, and only one sql query) when i have to list articles with these tags "(14 OR 16) AND (17 OR 18) AND NOT(13)" ? ... (negation, conjunction, disjunction) ...
Thank you for your help and ideas!

---

**SAMPLE TABLE: articles_x_tags**

```
╔════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ _id_tag(int11) ║ _id_article(int11) ║
╠════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ 14             ║ 2566               ║
║ 17             ║ 2566               ║
║ 13             ║ 2566               ║
║ 14             ║ 2567               ║
║ 17             ║ 2567               ║
║ 14             ║ 2568               ║
║ ...            ║ ... milion records ║
╚════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  id_article
FROM
  articles_x_tags
WHERE
  id_tag IN (14, 16, 17, 18, 13)
GROUP BY
  id_article
HAVING
  SUM(id_tag=14 OR id_tag=16)>0
  AND SUM(id_tag=17 OR id_tag=18)>0
  AND SUM(id_tag=13)=0
```

Comment: Its good for some cases, but I'm lookig for universal approach. This query doesnot work when I need to list tags "NOT(13 AND 19 AND 17)" ... conjuction inside negation ...  :-(

Comment: @JiříDoubravský oh okay, I understand your point... your question is interesting, I'll think if there's a better approach